# jQuery: Replace and remove HTML snippet on hover

Tags: jquery, html

I'm extremely new to jQuery.  I'm trying to have it so that the text in a **td** is replaced with a HTML snippet when the **tr** is hovered over and then reverted back to the original **td** content afterward.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will do it:

```
var originalContent = $('.myTR td').html();
$('.myTR').hover(function() {
     $('.myTR td').html('<strong>New HTML</strong>');   
}, function() {
     $('.myTR td').html(originalContent); 
});
```

Assuming your HTML looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr class="myTR">
        <td>Text td</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/G9Dnu/)

Answer (score 0):

IF your HTML looks something like this:

```
<table>
<tr id="hoverRow">
    <td id="contentCell" style="background-color: blue;">Content to Replace</td>
    <td>Other Content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You can do something like this:

```
<style type="text/javascript">
    var savedHtml = $('#contentCell').html();
    $('#hoverRow').hover(
        function () {
          $('#contentCell').html('New content');
          $('#contentCell').attr('background-color', 'red');
        }, 
        function () {
          $('#contentCell').html(savedHtml);
          $('#contentCell').attr('background-color', 'blue');
        }
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this, but you'll need something like a hidden field, or some other variable to stash the original content.

Something like this html:

```
<table id="table">
    <tr id="tr">
        <td>Some Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input id="hidden" type="hidden" />
```

And this jQuery:

```
$('#tr').hover(
    function(){
       $('#hidden').val($('#tr > td').text());
       $('#tr > td').text('Some Other Text');
    }, 
    function(){
        $('#tr > td').text($('#hidden').val());    
    }
);
```

See it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/davecoulter/HgAyv/